# Datatables - How do I change background and text color of a cell changed dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, cell, background-color

I use the following code to update a cell dynamically and works perfect, the only thing is how to change the color of the background and the text of that cell data. If it´s possible an example of how to change the entire row as well. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
        var data = this.data();       
        console.log(data);

        data[0] = '* ' + data[0];

        this.data(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I supose you have the background and content properties coming within the data object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

You can access the cell node by using [`cell().node()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.node%28%29) API method.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
        var cell = table.cell({ row: rowIdx, column: 0 }).node();
        $(cell).addClass('warning');
    });
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/986capby/486/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Brilliant ! I wish this could be present in Datatables documentation!

Comment: @marti_, API method [`rows().every()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) is available since DataTables v.1.10.6. Check your DataTables version or maybe use `table.rows().eq(0).each(function ( rowIdx ) {` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much :D